# What is the cause of getting empty array list

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpql

> I have 9 records in my database ,I want to fetch data using Id, I need
> all the data of given ID, But when I try to fetch the data using JPQL
> I am getting empty data in my console and my postman
> Here is all the details of my code work
> EmployeeRepository

```
package com.nilmani.workload.repository

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Bank
import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Employee
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam

interface EmployeeRepository : JpaRepository<Employee,Long> {
@Query(" SELECT  e.bankDetails from  Employee e where e.id= :id")
    fun findBankDetails(id: Long):Long
}
```

> EmployeeController

```
package com.nilmani.workload.controller

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.*
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.*
import com.nilmani.workload.model.response.*
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class ManagerController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository

/**Get User details using UserId*/
    @GetMapping("/my")
    fun singleUser(@ModelAttribute request:ReqSingleUser){
           val existUser:List<Employee> = employeeRepository.getEmployeesById(request.id)
        existUser.forEach ({
            println(existUser)
        })

    }
}
```

> ModelClass

```
package com.nilmani.workload.model.request

data class ReqSingleUser(
    val id:Long=-1
)
```

> What is the reason for getting empty data,But already data present in
> my database
> I am using IntelliJ IDEA as code editor, mac as operating system
> EmployeeEntityClass

```
package com.nilmani.workload.entity

import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqBank
import javax.persistence.*


@Entity
data class Employee(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val name:String="",
    val mobile:Long=-1,
    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinTable(
        name = "emp_workstation",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "bank_id", referencedColumnName = "id")]
    )
    val bankDetails: Bank,
    val address:String=""
)
```

Comment: Can you share Employee model code ?

Comment: I added my employee entity class ,Now you can check it

Comment: how does your request look like? can you share the `curl` command? Print the incoming `request.id` and see if you are getting right request object. Also try using `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: http://localhost:8083/test/my.  this is the my request url

Comment: if it is the GET request, how are you sending the request body? where are you specifying the ID? are you using `form` on the front end?